# Nested Loop with variables

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to print a value inside the j(innermost) loop. However,my j loop is not working. I am not sure what's causing it as I tried every possible way to make it work to print values in j
loop.

How can I make the loop work ?

Comment: What does "not working" mean, exactly?

Comment: the print option inside j loop is not printing anything. not even when you print('j')

Comment: `range(x, y, 2)` does not contain any numbers when `x > y` (which is the case here). Did you mean the step to be `-2` rather than `2` so you iterate in reverse?

Comment: yeah. I did the mistake. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, left border of inner loop is always greater than right one. You can either swap them or use a negative step in `range` if you really want to iterate from greater to smaller.

Right now your step is positive and equals `2`.

Here's how I figured it out:

```
m = 961
n = 220
for i in range(2-1, m-3):
    #print ("test: i loop is working")
    print((2*n*(i+5)-1), (2*n*(i+1)-5))
    for j in range((2*n*(i+5)-1), (2*n*(i+1)-5),2):
        
        print ("test: j is not working")
```

Output (truncated):

```
2639 875
3079 1315
3519 1755
3959 2195
4399 2635
4839 3075
5279 3515
5719 3955
...
```

Comment: thank you for indentifying the mistake